# Keep an element as constant on Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I want to keep one element of the formula as "constant" but without writing it as a number in the formula e.g.

I have this function:

```
=COUNTBLANK(B2:M2)*Q1+N2
```

And if I drag it to the rows below it it completes the function as:

```
=COUNTBLANK(B3:M3)*Q2+N3
=COUNTBLANK(B4:M4)*Q3+N4
...
```

However, I want to keep the `Q1` as a defined value that doesn't change in that formula i.e

```
=COUNTBLANK(B3:M3)*Q1+N3
=COUNTBLANK(B4:M4)*Q1+N4
...
```

I know I could just define the formula as:

```
=COUNTBLANK(B4:M4)*7+N4 // Or any numeric value, but I would prefer to keep it as Q1.
```

Comment: Anchor it with a $:  Q$1.  The 1 won't auto-adjust when you copy it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cell reference will auto-adjust when you copy it, which is handy for developing a formula and then populating it to other cells.  When you don't want that assist, and need a reference to remain constant when you copy it to other cells, anchor the row and/or column you want to remain constant by prefixing it with a `$`.

- **Q$1** will continue to point to row 1 when you copy it down the column, but the `Q` will change if you copy the formula to another column.  So copying the formula to the cell one column to the right and two columns down will give you a reference to `R$1` in the new cell.
- **$Q1** will continue to point to Column Q when you copy the formula to other columns, but the `1` will change if you copy it down to other rows.  Copying the formula to the cell one column to the right and two columns down will give you a reference to `$Q3` in the new cell.
- **$Q$1** will anchor both the Q and the 1.  Copying the formula to the cell one column to the right and two columns down will give you a reference to `$Q$1` in the new cell.